# Concept of "Roberts Cross Operator"

Tags: java

I would like to know the concept behind an edge-finding "Roberts Cross Operator" - How does it work? How is it implemented?

(Please do not use code; I want to code it myself.)

Comment: Do you have difficulty understanding the explanations that come up if you [Google `roberts cross operator`](https://www.google.com/search?q=roberts+cross+operator)?  If so, what parts do you have trouble with?

Comment: I don't understand how it's "implemented" and how it's written, really. Is it some sort of mathematical formula, with a forloop that looks through pixels?

Comment: *"no code please"*  +1  Not only for requesting no code, but being polite about it.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You iterate over every pixel in the source image, and compute the value of the corresponding pixel in the destination image based on the value of the source pixel and its neighbors to the east, south, and southeast.

Comment: Thank you, now I now perfectly where to start!